# errored: Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Tags: remix, gas, gas-limit, error

Hi I have this error :

`transact to Roulette.betSingle errored: Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction`

My programm :

```
contract Roulette {

uint public lastRoundTimestamp;
uint public nextRoundTimestamp;

address _creator;
uint _interval;

enum BetType { Single, Odd, Even }

struct Bet {
    BetType betType;
    address player;
    uint number;
    uint value;
}

Bet[] public bets;

function getBetsCountAndValue() public constant returns(uint, uint) {
    uint value = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < bets.length; i++) {
        value += bets[i].value;
    }
    return (bets.length, value);
}

event Finished(uint number, uint nextRoundTimestamp);

modifier transactionMustContainEther() {
    if (msg.value == 0) throw;
    _;
}

modifier bankMustBeAbleToPayForBetType(BetType betType) {
    uint necessaryBalance = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < bets.length; i++) {
        necessaryBalance += getPayoutForType(bets[i].betType) * bets[i].value;
    }
    necessaryBalance += getPayoutForType(betType) * msg.value;
    if (necessaryBalance > this.balance) throw;
    _;
}

function getPayoutForType(BetType betType) constant returns(uint) {
    if (betType == BetType.Single) return 35;
    if (betType == BetType.Even || betType == BetType.Odd) return 2;
    return 0;
}

function Roulette(uint interval) {
    _interval = interval;
    _creator = msg.sender;
    nextRoundTimestamp = 1517784279 + _interval;
}

function betSingle(uint number) public payable transactionMustContainEther() bankMustBeAbleToPayForBetType(BetType.Single) {
    if (number > 36) throw;
    bets.push(Bet({
        betType: BetType.Single,
        player: msg.sender,
        number: number,
        value: msg.value
    }));
}

function betEven() public payable transactionMustContainEther() bankMustBeAbleToPayForBetType(BetType.Even) {
    bets.push(Bet({
        betType: BetType.Even,
        player: msg.sender,
        number: 0,
        value: msg.value
    }));
}

function betOdd() public payable transactionMustContainEther() bankMustBeAbleToPayForBetType(BetType.Odd) {
    bets.push(Bet({
        betType: BetType.Odd,
        player: msg.sender,
        number: 0,
        value: msg.value
    }));
}

function launch() public {
    if (now < nextRoundTimestamp) throw;

    uint number = uint(block.blockhash(block.number - 1)) % 37;

    for (uint i = 0; i < bets.length; i++) {
        bool won = false;
        uint payout = 0;
        if (bets[i].betType == BetType.Single) {
            if (bets[i].number == number) {
                won = true;
            }
        } else if (bets[i].betType == BetType.Even) {
            if (number > 0 && number % 2 == 0) {
                won = true;
            }
        } else if (bets[i].betType == BetType.Odd) {
            if (number > 0 && number % 2 == 1) {
                won = true;
            }
        }
        if (won) {
            if (bets[i].player.send(bets[i].value * getPayoutForType(bets[i].betType)))
            throw;
        }
    }

    uint thisRoundTimestamp = nextRoundTimestamp;
    nextRoundTimestamp = thisRoundTimestamp + _interval;
    lastRoundTimestamp = thisRoundTimestamp;

    bets.length = 0;

    Finished(number, nextRoundTimestamp);
}

}
```

HELP ME PLEASE ! :)

Comment: I compile this program with remix

Comment: You get this error when submitting program to network? Or when you try to run the contract?

Comment: when i submit a method. The contract is deployed normally. Sorry for my english i'am french lol

Comment: How many bets do you have? getBetsCountAndValue() is bad practice to do for loops. Too many bets and you will exceed gas amount for the block.

Comment: i have test just for 1 bet and it doesn't work. It's just for test the contract. One bet don't work

Comment: Please tell me exactly the call you are making, which function, what parameters, your gas, your gasPrice.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is caused by this lines

```
    necessaryBalance += getPayoutForType(betType) * msg.value;
    if (necessaryBalance > this.balance) throw;
```

At the beginning this.balance is zero.

When you call betSingle for the first time `msg.value` will be equal to `this.balance`. Now `getPayoutForType(betType)` will return 35.

And then `necessaryBalance = 35 * msg.value` and the check `if (necessaryBalance > this.balance) throw` will always be true causing the throws and reverse all changes to the contract.

The other bets functions will fail similarly, blocking the contract.

---

A few advices:

- Avoid using throw, it is considered a bad practice, you should use require or assert.
- Avoid unbounded for/while loops, they can cause out of gas errors if you have too many itaerations.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons when a transaction requires too much gas to run is because the contract throws an exception.  I noticed a few places where exceptions can be thrown in betSingle():

- calling betSingle() with input > 36
- throw in the modifier, transactionMustContainEther() if the transaction does not have a value amount
- throw in the modifier, bankMustBeAbleToPayForBetType() if the contract does not have a balance to pay for the bet.  Make sure the contract is created with a initial balance.